# Looping - python

Tags: python, list, loops

```
words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
code = ['3' , '2', '4' , '9']
```

I have two lists that the user must try and match together. In order to do this, they have to alter the 'code' list:

```
number = input("Enter a number: ")
letter = input("Enter the letter: ")

code =list(map(lambda x: str.replace(x, number, letter), code))
```

How can I loop this so that the user has to keep changing the numbers for the 'code' list until it matches the 'words' list?

I've tried using

```
while code != words:
```

but it doesn't work properly because during the second time, the changes I made from the first instance aren't present.

Comment: What code have you tried yet?

Comment: Am I missing something or do you not just need `while words != code: #do something` ???

Comment: I've tried while words!= code

Comment: @user3403623 : which should work.

Comment: ...and what happened? You are failing to provide a lot of crucial context. Are you ever changing the `code` list? You are assigning it to some unspecified thing called `Guess` above. Maybe `while words != Guess` ? Or maybe tell us more about what you are doing?

Comment: This never alters the code list. Do you want to match words with code or guess with code?

Comment: you have no comma separating the 4 and 9, which Python concatenates implicitly.

Comment: Sorry (silly mistakes made) - I've edited my question so please check it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are just not reassigning the user's guess (the lambda manipulation) to the proper `code` variable. I'm guessing through the question, but this seems like what you are trying to do:

```
words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
code = ['3' , '2', '4', '9']

while words != code:
    number = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    letter = raw_input("Enter the letter: ")
    code = list(map(lambda x: str.replace(x, number, letter), code))

print('You finally got it!')
```

Comment: Although this will do all kinds of very, very bad things if the user enters stuff that isn't numbers in python 2.x

Comment: Yes, if this is Python2, you want `raw_input` rather than `input`. Answer changed to reflect that.

Comment: Yep, that was the point of my comment. But again this doesn't let you account gracefully for what happens if they don't enter a letter/number or if they enter valid input by with whitespace. In other words this works for perfect input, but is weak to bad input.

Comment: @aruisdante Yes, I see that now. `input` works as expected in Py3k. And you are right. This assumes a very kind user.

Comment: Mm. I definitely like how sexy doing an infinite map call is though. The inner scheme programmer in me could only be more excited if you used recursion instead of a while loop :p

Comment: This would get very confusing before very long - if they ever change a number to a letter, then they would need to enter that letter instead of a number in order to change it to anything else.

Comment: @RobWatts It is certainly not a game I'd want to play for very long.

Answer (score 2):

Is the code list invariant?

If so, you could do the following:

```
def guess(code, words):
    print('The Code Is: '+str(code))
    guess = raw_input('Enter A List Of Letters, Separated by Commas: ')
    guess = guess.split(',')
    guess = [letter.strip() for letter in guess]
    number_correct = 0
    for index in range(min(len(guess), len(words))):
        if guess[index] = words[index]
        number_correct += 1
    if number_correct == len(words):
       print('You Got It!')
       return True
    else:
       print('You Got {0} of {1} Letters Right! Try Again...'.format(number_correct, len(words))
       return guess(code, words)
```

Comment: Given the question, this is at the very least a heroic attempt at a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that what you actually want is two loops, one for waiting until they guess right, and one for gathering their guess:

```
words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
code = ['3' , '2', '4' , '9']

guess = None
while guess != words:
    print 'Enter 4 number/letter pairs'
    guess = code
    for i in range(4):
        number = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
        letter = raw_input("Enter the letter: ")
        guess = list(map(lambda x: str.replace(x, number, letter), guess))
if guess == words:
    print 'You got it!'
else:
    print 'Nope! Guess again!'
```

This way the guess is reset each time. If you don't do that, then after 4 times the working list for the code (`guess` in my code here) might be something like this:

```
>>> print guess
['3', 'd', 'y', '9']
```

If it looks like this, then to fix it, they would have to enter a *letter*/letter pair, rather than a number/letter pair. To make things worse, you could even have it get into a state where it becomes impossible to get it right. For example, if `guess` looks like this:

```
['3', 'a', 'a', '9']
```

If you try to change one of the `'a'`s to anything else, then the other `'a'` will change as well. Seeing as the result you're trying to get has them as being different, then there is no way to get the correct result from this `guess`.

If you really do want each guess to carry on until the user gets it all correct, I'd suggest a different strategy:

```
words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
code = ['3' , '2', '4' , '9']
mapping = {}

guess = None
while guess != words:
    number = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    letter = raw_input("Enter the letter: ")
    mapping[number] = letter
    guess = [mapping.get(entry, entry) for entry in code]
print 'You got it!'
```

This strategy will overwrite any previous guess and effectively make it so they are always working with the original code.

Whatever strategy you choose, it would probably be a good idea to give the user some idea of what they've already guessed. In my second example, you could print out the mapping (in some nice format). Here's an idea for how you could print it:

```
print '\n'.join('%s->%s' % (number, letter) for number, letter in sorted(test.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

This would print `{'1': 'a', '3': 'c', '2': 'b'}` like this:

```
1->a
2->b
3->c
```